# Slim3 route placeholders are not be converted to array

Tags: php, api, slim

I am testing Slim3 and following the examples from official documentation.

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
```

When doing var_dump($args), it shows non array output that is value of id

```
    // Show book identified by $args['id']
});
```

I documentation, it looks like $args is array in callback function, but not working for me.

Any idea, why?

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is correct. That is an array, you only have id as an placeholder on your route.

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders